# Android can't read picture stored in phone memory, only works on pictures stored in sd card

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an app that takes pictures then i read them, 
when pictures are stored in SD card i can read them fine but when they are stored in phone memory i can find them (newFile  displays correct path) but i don't see them in the image view. In samsung phones they are stored in /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AppImages in cases like this is when i can't read and display in ImageView

```
     File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AppImages"); 

final ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);

    File newFile = new File(mediaStorageDir+File.separator+files.getString(2));  

    //I have tried this 3 options one at a time
    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(newFile));
    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newFile.getPath());

    newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried MediaStore?

Look at this:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI //from external storage
MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI //from internal storage
```

Take a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)

Comment: I tried your answer but culdn't find how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was displaying the full pictures in the gallery, resizing them to thumbnails size fixed the issue.